# Create pandas dataframe by repeating one row with new multiindex

Tags: pandas, dataframe, creation

In Pandas I have a series and a multi-index:

```
s = pd.Series([1,2,3,4], index=['w', 'x', 'y', 'z'])
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']])
```

What is the best way for me to create a DataFrame that has idx as index, and s as value for each row, preserving the index in S as columns?

```
df =
       w   x   y   z
a  c   1   2   3   4
   d   1   2   3   4
b  c   1   2   3   4
   d   1   2   3   4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `pd.DataFrame` constructor followed by `assign`

```
pd.DataFrame(index=idx).assign(**s)

     w  x  y  z
a c  1  2  3  4
  d  1  2  3  4
b c  1  2  3  4
  d  1  2  3  4
```

Comment: This is a very smart solution!

Comment: This is super interesting. The only thing I will note is that `assign` shuffles the order of `s` based on its index (see the Notes section in [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html#notes)). So if the index names are `['w', 'x', 'y', 'a']` instead, column `a` will jump to the front. But that's OK for my purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`numpy.repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) with [`numpy.ndarray.reshape`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.reshape.html) for duplicate data and last `DataFrame` constructor:

```
arr = np.repeat(s.values, len(idx)).reshape(-1, len(idx))
df = pd.DataFrame(arr, index=idx, columns=s.index)
print (df)
     w  x  y  z
a c  1  1  1  1
  d  2  2  2  2
b c  3  3  3  3
  d  4  4  4  4
```

**Timings**:

```
np.random.seed(123)
s = pd.Series(np.random.randint(10, size=1000))
s.index = s.index.astype(str)
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([np.random.randint(10, size=250), ['a','b','c', 'd']])

In [32]: %timeit (pd.DataFrame(np.repeat(s.values, len(idx)).reshape(len(idx), -1), index=idx, columns=s.index))
100 loops, best of 3: 3.94 ms per loop

In [33]: %timeit (pd.DataFrame(index=idx).assign(**s))
1 loop, best of 3: 332 ms per loop

In [34]: %timeit pd.DataFrame([s]*len(idx),idx,s.index)
10 loops, best of 3: 82.9 ms per loop
```

Comment: thank you! I learned much from your answers to this (and other) question that there is a trade off between speed and syntactic localization within Pandas. I understand now that if I can resort to numpy more often, my speed can go up!

Comment: Ya, if performance is not important, all solutions are nice, good lukc!

Answer (score 0):

Use [s]*len(s) as data, idx as index and s.index as column to reconstruct a df.

```
pd.DataFrame([s]*len(s),idx,s.index)
Out[56]: 
     w  x  y  z
a c  1  2  3  4
  d  1  2  3  4
b c  1  2  3  4
  d  1  2  3  4
```

Comment: This only works coincidentally because `len(s) == len(idx)`.  Try `s = pd.Series([0,1,2,3,4], index=['v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'])` and it fails.  You want this instead `pd.DataFrame([s]*len(idx),idx,s.index)`