# How to re-index as multi-index pandas dataframe from index value that repeats

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have an index in a pandas dataframe which repeats the index value. I want to re-index as multi-index where repeated indexes are grouped.

The indexing looks like such:

[image]

so I would like all the 112335586 index values would be grouped under the same in index.

I have looked at this question [Create pandas dataframe by repeating one row with new multiindex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44666608/create-pandas-dataframe-by-repeating-one-row-with-new-multiindex) but here the value can be index can be pre-defined but this is not possible as my dataframe is far too large to hard code this.

I also looked at at the multi-index documentation but this also pre-defines the value for the index.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you need:

```
s = pd.Series([1,2,3,4], index=[10,10,20,20])
s.index.name = 'EVENT_ID'
print (s)
EVENT_ID
10    1
10    2
20    3
20    4
dtype: int64

s1 = s.index.to_series()
s2 = s1.groupby(s1).cumcount()
s.index = [s.index, s2]
print (s)
EVENT_ID   
10        0    1
          1    2
20        0    3
          1    4
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me @jezrael. For line two of your code, I am getting an error 
 for series having no attribute set_index.

Comment: @sandycaskie - Answer was edited, can you check now?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df['sub_idx'] = df.groupby('EVENT_ID').cumcount()
df.set_index(['EVENT_ID','sub_idx'], inplace=True)
```